# How to return multiple results in the same cell using Index, Match and Search

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, textjoin

I have a working Index, Match, Search formula that searches the titles of my products for specific terms that I've determined in a Key, if no result is found then alternatively it searches my product SKU's using a different key.

Currently, the formula is only giving me the first result that it finds within my key but I would like it to return as many results as possible all separated by Pipes or commas.

Here's the working formula that is giving me 1 result.

`=IF((ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$J:$J,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$I:$I,$B2)),0))))="",(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$L:$L,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$K:$K,$A2)),0)))),(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$J:$J,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$I:$I,$B2)),0)))))`

This would be awesome if I could get it working. Here's a link to a copy of my spreadsheet if anyone would like to see it working. Feel free to make any edits.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1APLCVnqmP51UbimyZeY-S0BoSEuFWkPa2LtAxVX9H0E/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried to use the following formula but it doesn't quite work how I'd like it to.

`=IF((ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$F:$F,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$E:$E,$B2)),0))))="",(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$H:$H,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$G:$G,$A2)),0)))),(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$F:$F,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$E:$E,$B2)),0)))))&" | "&(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Array Key'!$H:$H,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Array Key'!$G:$G,$A2)),0))))`

This formula searches the 2nd key again and concatenates any results. However, I'm getting duplicates and it still only returns the first result found.

Comment: You should look into `TEXTJOIN()` function :)

Comment: I've had a little look into I just have no idea how to apply it to my formula :(

Comment: Is there any reason why you tagged `Excel` at all, cause right now another user removed it from the question. If it has no relevance you should leave it out.

Comment: what should be the desired output of D2 cell??

Comment: I'm currently working in google sheets but if Excel has a function that google sheets doesn't have to get this working then I'd also like to know :) Sorry if this is the wrong way to tag a post.

Comment: The desired output for cell D2 would be War | Horror as in the Array Key tab in cells E25 and cell E41 death has 2 categories that I would like to assign in cell D2

Comment: It's fine, but it wasn't quite clear from the question. You can re-edit your question if you desire so and re-tag `Excel`. But most likely all this can be done through GS

Comment: it makes no sense D2 to be what you want it to be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this would be like:

[image]

---

then **D2** cell would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" | ", 1, UNIQUE({
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B2, " "), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Array Key'!E$3:E)))), 'Array Key'!E$3:F, 2, 0));
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2, " "), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Array Key'!G$3:G)))), 'Array Key'!G$3:H, 2, 0))})))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's brilliant. That works exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi, I've just picked this project up again after a little break and I was wondering if you could possibly help? Here's a link to the sheet that I'm working on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nK6N0DwaXTYcMD8kSDlFYf1hqOFNxnakONE1tWtBOL4/edit?usp=sharing I can't quite figure out why I'm getting some results. For example, the "Star Wars" products I've highlighted in dark grey aren't being assigned a theme, even though the word "Star Wars" exists in the title (As you can see in the Array Key tab on row 103 "Star Wars" exists there)

Comment: check your sheet now